# Is it possible to add an Attribute using HTMLDocument?

Tags: java, html, dom, attributes

The objective is to check for specific attribute and if not found then append it to the list of existing attributes.

Although there may be other options available, this example is restricted to working with the HTMLDocument object and associated objects.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;

class AddAttributeTest 
{
    
    static String srg = "<html> " + 
            "  <head>" + 
            "      Hello World" + 
            "  </head>" + 
            "  <body a1=\"ABC\" a2=\"3974\" a3=\"A1B2\">     " + 
            "    <H1>Start Here<H1>" + 
            "    <p>This is the body</p>" + 
            "  </body>" + 
            "</html>" ;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
        HTMLDocument doc = new HTMLDocument();//

        try
        {
            Reader rd = new StringReader(srg); 
            kit.read(rd, doc, 0);
            ElementIterator it = new ElementIterator(doc);
            Element elem = null;

            while ( (elem = it.next()) != null )
            {
                if (elem.getName().equals("body"))
                {
                    AttributeSet as = elem.getAttributes();
                    if (as.isDefined("a1"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("a1 exists : " + as.getAttribute("a1"));
                    }
                    
                    if (as.isDefined("a4"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("a4 exists : " + as.getAttribute("a4"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("a4 is missing and need to add");
                        //Add the missing attribute to the end of the existing list of attributes.
                        //elem - only get....() calls exist.
                        //as - only get...() calls and checks exist. 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

This example illustrates that it is able to find the "a1" attribute and print out its value.

```
a1 exists : ABC
a4 is missing and need to add
```

Next it attempts to locate the "a4" attribute which it does not find and attempts to add it.

Using Eclipse I have check available calls for both the Element & AttributeSet objects and they are all getters() or boolean checks. There weren't any "add" routines or setters() to call.

Searching and any references to adding attributes are implemented in a variety of different ways except for how I am trying to do it.

Is it possible to implement it using HTMLDocument and associated calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to edit using HTMLDocument you will need to use writeLock() and writeUnlock(). These methods are protected, so you need to extend HtmlDocument to expose those methods publicly.

```
public static class MyHTMLDocument extends HTMLDocument {
    public void doWriteLock() {
        writeLock();
    }
    
    public void doWriteUnlock() {
        writeUnlock();
    }
}
```

In your code, use an instance of MyHTMLDocument instead of HTMLDocument:

```
MyHTMLDocument doc = new MyHTMLDocument();
```

and add the missing a4 attribute as follows:

```
doc.doWriteLock();
((BlockElement) elem).addAttribute("a4", "value");
doc.doWriteUnlock();
```

Comment: Thanks. No way would I have been able to interpret the docs to design the above. In fact searching on "HTMLDocument dowriteLock" doesn't return any information. Are there any issues/concerns with this implementation?

Comment: Search for HTMLDocument.writeLock() -- that is listed as protected final, so you cannot override it. In MyHTMLDocument you basically created a new public method (any name, I just chose doWriteLock) which calls the protected writeLock().

Comment: it appears this addAttribute() call also works when replacing a value. Would this indeed be the correct call to use when updating?